# Python web.py redirect using Jinja2

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2, web.py

I have the classes in main module

**__init__.py**

```
import web
from web.contrib.template import render_jinja

urls = (
  '/', 'main.views.login',
  '/login', 'main.views.login',
  '/feature', 'main.views.feature'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())
render = render_jinja(
        'main/templates',
        encoding='utf-8',
    )
```

**views.py**

```
from main import web, render
class login:
    def GET(self):
        return render.login(title="Login")

    def POST(self):
        data = web.input();
        userName = data['username']
        password = data['password']
        if((userName == 'viv') and (password == 'viv')):
            raise web.seeother('/feature?user=' + userName)
        return render.login(error="Login Failed !!!")
class feature:
    def GET(self):
        print(web.input())
        return render.feature()
```

In login.POST , the form data is compared and if successful i need to redirect to feature.html which has

```
<div>Hello {{ user }}</div>
```

Using JINJA2 templating with web.py how can i redirect to feature.html with parameter 'user'. The above code works but 'user' is send as URL parameter .Basically i want to try web.py redirect with JINJA2 templating.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your `user` information into the `render.feature()` call.

```
class feature:
    def GET(self):
        return render.feature(user=web.input().user)
```

This works because `web.input()` will get the results of POST (when called within `class login`, and gets the URL parameters with a GET (when called within `class feature`.) So your redirect to `/feature` is working fine, but you need to pass the information into the template renderer so you can print the results!

Comment: Is there any other way to pass parameter while redirecting other than appending to URL ?

Comment: Have login.POST "create a session" by storing session_id and logged in user information into a database. Drop the session_id as a cookie.   Then, in the feature.GET, read the cookie, do a database read converting session_id into your logged-in user's information.